# A Java program to print all subsets of a set/ Converting String to char[]

Tags: java, recursion, subset

I want to find all subsets of a set Recursively and here is the code I have. My problem is with this part:

```
char[] set = in.nextLine().toCharArray().split("(?!^)");
```

when I run this code, i get this error and I dont know how to solve it.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
Cannot invoke split(String) on the array type char[]

at subsetGeek.Main.main(Main.java:35)
```

I want to take the Set from the user with this part of code an put it into a char[] and then show the subsets.

```
// A Java program to print all subsets of a set
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    class Main
    {
        // Print all subsets of given set[]
        static void printSubsets(char set[])
        {
            int n = set.length;

        // Run a loop for printing all 2^n
        // subsets one by obe
        for (int i = 0; i < (1<<n); i++)
        {
            System.out.print("{ ");

            // Print current subset
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)

                // (1<<j) is a number with jth bit 1
                // so when we 'and' them with the
                // subset number we get which numbers
                // are present in the subset and which
                // are not
                if ((i & (1 << j)) > 0)
                    System.out.print(set[j] + " ");

            System.out.println("}");
        }
    }

    // Driver code
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        char[] set = in.nextLine().toCharArray().split("(?!^)");
        //char set[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
        printSubsets(set);
    }
}
```

Is there anything else that can be replaced with that part of my code?

Comment: You convert the `String` into a `char[]` by calling `in.nextLine().toCharArray()`. You cannot call `split(...)` on a `char[]`.

Comment: It looks like all you need to do is replace `char[] set = in.nextLine().toCharArray().split("(?!^)");` with `char[] set = in.nextLine().split("(?!^)").toCharArray();` according to the exception given.

Comment: @BallisticBlaze `split("(?!^)").toCharArray()`? Arrays don't really have methods, and I'm not sure what `String[].toCharArray` would even do...

Comment: Ah, forgot about that, splitting seems to be more difficult than I thought. A multidimensional char array perhaps?

Comment: Yes, I tried that and I get another error :    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Cannot invoke toCharArray() on the array type String[]

 at subsetGeek.Main.main(Main.java:35)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your error line of code with below code.

```
char[] set = in.nextLine().replaceAll("[?!^]","").toCharArray();
```